# How to get other properties from an LDAP principal (user) after login using Glassfish's LDAPRealm?

Tags: security, jsf, authentication, glassfish, ldap

How can I get properties from a user after he successfully logged into my app, which is running on a Glassfish configured with a LDAP Realm?

Here's my scenario:

- I have a LDAPRealm configured in my Glassfish which works fine.
- I use form-based authentication. The form is a JSF page that works fine too.
- I have a LoginBean which logins the user like this:

  ```
  HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
  .getCurrentInstance()
  .getExternalContext()
  .getRequest();
  req.login(this.user, this.password);
  Principal p = req.getUserPrincipal();
  ```

My question is: how can I get, say, the email, givenName (or any other property my LDAP offers) of this Principal?

(I've done lots of googling but still no luck)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should all be in the `Subject` that was created by the realm. Keep looking.

Comment: couldn't found anything about it at all. If you do have the answer, I'd really appreciate you telling me.

Comment: Haven't used GlassFish-specific security myself, but from looking at the sources of the [LDAPRealm](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/tags/3.1.2/security/core/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/realm/ldap/LDAPRealm.java) and [LDAPLoginModule] (https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/tags/3.1.2/security/core/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/login/LDAPLoginModule.java) I'm afraid that only *dn* and group-related attributes are retrieved and inserted into the `Subject` as `Principal`s.

Comment: If that's the case, you'd either need to extend at least the proprietary JAAS login module, or implement a standard `javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule` in order to insert additional `Principal`s encapsulating the necessary LDAP attributes (or a single "rich" `Principal`) into the `Subject`. Or alternatively forget about standard security and query the LDAP anew from within your application, or let some security framework external to Java EE do it for you.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If so, could you tell us how?

Comment: @luis Check Uux's comment above for it's very useful. I've dropped that idea of getting the info from JAAS and started obtaining what I need by querying my LDAP server.